# any semblance of a DOJ investigation

Tags: word-meaning

The meaning of "semblance" is not clear to me.  "any semblance of a Department of Justice investigation" seems "any unexpected action of a DOJ investigation". Just a wild guess here.

Cambridge Dictionary defines "semblance" as "a situation or condition that is similar to what is wanted or expected, but is not exactly as hoped for". I don't know how to make it fit in the context below.

> "With all due respect to the Attorney General, there hasn't been any semblance of a Department of Justice investigation............"

> Source: Judy Giuliani and Jenna Ellis' statement on Barr's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tthe construction "There hasn't been any semblance of an X" (wherever X may be) is often used to mean that there not only hasn't been X, but that there hasn't been anything resembling or approximating X, indeed that there hasn't been any hint of X. It is a **stronger** statement than "There hasn't been any X". This is a not uncommon construction, although not used in very informal writing, and more often in writing than in speech.

Examples:

- (of a legal situation) "He doesn't have any semblance of a case." meaning that he not only doesn't have a case, he doesn't even have a faint approach to or start of a case.
- "She doesn't show any semblance of affection to him." meaning that she shows no suggestion or hint oif liking.
- "His performance has no semblance of talent."  meaning that there is no trace of talent in the performance.

Answer (score 4):

The definition you gave for "semblance" is correct for this context. By "there hasn't been any semblance of a DOJ investigation" they mean "there hasn't been anything close to what could be considered a DOJ investigation." In other words, they don't believe a DOJ investigation has taken place.